# Scala SortedSet: I cannot get how ordering works

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How can I sort my Tag elements by id ?

I don't get how to define the orderById function...

```
case class Tag(id: Int, name: String, ttype: String)

val orderByID = Ordering[??].on[Tag](? => ? -> ?)

val mySet: SortedSet[Tag] = SortedSet()(orderByID) ;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need:

```
val orderByID = Ordering.by[Tag, Int](_.id)
val mySet: SortedSet[Tag] = SortedSet()(orderByID)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ordering.on` turns an `Ordering[U]` into an `Ordering[T]` given a function to produce a `U` from a `T`.  In this case, we need to start with an `Ordering[Int]`, then provide a `Tag => Int` function:

```
val orderByID = Ordering[Int].on[Tag](_.id)
```

But as @Lee has said, `Ordering.by` is a more straightforward approach here.